# How do you save chromes devtools as html when it's a lot of data?

Tags: html, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, devtools

I'm looking for a way to save chromes devtools as an html file, it's too large to copy to clipboard, and I can't dump the information I need as an HAR file as it's too large and results in a zero byte file. Any ideas?

Comment: It depends on what you want to copy specifically. Show a screenshot.

Comment: I don't have a screenshot since I closed it for now and it's a lot of data to download. It was websockett messages

Comment: If there was no `Copy` button nearby then there's no easy way: you'll have to open devtools-on-devtools ([example](/a/53972086)) and dig its internals (opening the [source code of devtools](https://chromium.googlesource.com/devtools/devtools-frontend/) in an IDE would be helpful).